# On the number of connected functional digraphs recoverable from the preimage set size structure

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, enumerative-combinatorics, directed-graphs, transformation-groups

I am studying the list of inverse images (preimage sets) of some function $f$ at a given inverse depth $j$  -- for each element $x_i$ of a finite domain $X$.

For example, 
        $P_j=\left[f^{-j}(x_1), f^{-j}(x_2), f^{-j}(x_3),\text{...},f^{-j}( x_n)\right]$

For each of these, we may populate the matrix

$P=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
 f^{-1}(x_{1}) & f^{-2}(x_{1}) & \cdots & f^{-n}(x_{1})\\
f^{-1}(x_{2}) & \ddots\\
\vdots\\
f^{-1}(x_{n}) &  &  & f^{-n}(x_{n})
\end{array}\right)$

However, of particular interest to me is what happens when we look at the *sizes* of such matrix elements. 
 Yielding a matrix $\Sigma$ with entries 

 
$\Sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
 \mid f^{-1}(x_{1})\mid  & \cdots & \mid f^{-n}(x_{1})\mid \\
&\ddots\\
\vdots\\
\mid f^{-1}(x_{n})\mid &  & \mid f^{-n}(x_{n})\mid
\end{array}\right)$

For example, for $f=(a,b),(b,a),(c,a)$ by calculating the second matrix we get $\Sigma_f=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

Now, each preimage size (Sigma) matrix has to it associated a set of functions which have the matrix as their Sigma matrix. This is the partition of functions $X^X$ by the matrix structure.

**I Suspect**: *1. In each class $[f]={g:\Sigma g=\Sigma f}$ there is only one single-component functional digraph. 2. There are no two functions with the same size cycle*

For example, for $f=(a,b),(b,a),(c,a),(d,b)$ and  $g=(a,a),(b,b),(c,a),(d,b)$ we have the same sigma matrix
$\Sigma_{f,g}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

However there is only one connected (maximal) functional digraph $f$

If anyone has some references or a suggestion on how to proceed I'd be grateful... I suspect that holding everything else the same, increasing/decreasing the cycle size in a connected functional digraph changes the preimage structure. Thus, to get cycles of length 1 (in the example above) the graph had to be disconnected. Similarly to increase the cycle size to 3 would require a different preimage structure...

Any help appreciated.

> Fournier, Bradford M., "Towards a Theory of Recursive Function
>   Complexity: Sigma Matrices and Inverse Complexity Measures" (2015).
>   University of New Orleans Theses and Dissertations. 2072.

https://scholarworks.uno.edu/td/2072